# Move tiles/textbox store location in db

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, godot

I have 25 rooms, in each room I have positions that can hold 1 or more objects, uniquely identified. I want to create a drag and drop system for the objects that will store the location in an SQL database, which is already setup and in use. I currently lookup the object then manually type in the desired location. I am looking for a graphical drag and drop way to accomplish this.
I am not sure where to begin to accomplish this. I was even thinking maybe a gaming engine would be a good option, Godot or Unity.  Here is a sample picture of what I thinking of.[movable tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa0HU.png)

Answer (score 1):

So you have `Rooms` and `StoredItems`. Every `Room` contains zero or more `StoredItems`, every `StoredItem` is stored in exactly one `Room`.

This is a straightforward one-to-many relation. In a relational datbase this is implemented by giving the items on the "many" side a foreign key that refers to the primary key of the item that it belongs to.

In your case: both `Rooms` and `StoredItems` get a unique primary key. `StoredItems` also get a foreign key that refers to the Id of the `Room` that the item is stored in.

An easy and fairly intuitive way to set up your database is by using nuget package entity framework.

If you use entity framework you can execute almost all queries using standard C#. Entity framework will translate them to the database language, which is usually SQL.

If you use entity framework you will have the following classes:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Room contains zero ore more StoredItems (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<StoredItem> StoredItems {get; set;}
}

public class StoredItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every StoredItem is stored in exactly one Room, using foreign key
    public int RoomId {get; set;}
    public virtual Room Room {get; set;}
}
```

So you will have the following tables

```
Room         StoredItem  
Id ..        Id RoomId ...
01 ...       01 01
02 ...       02 01
Etc.         03 03
             04 02
             05 02
             06 05
```

From these tables you can see that StoredItem [04] is stored in Room [02], and that Room [01] contains two StoredItems, namely StoredItem [01] and [02]

If you want to know more about entity framework visit [Entity Framework tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Great explanation of the logic behind the scenes. As for implementing the UI, this could be done in Godot by setting your StoredItems `pickable_input = true`. This will allow you to detect mouse events inside them and update the specific item's position. `position = get_global_mouse_position()` each frame - creating the dragging effect.